# Django social networking site with heroku

Tags: python, django, apache, heroku, social-networking

Iam in a plan to develop a social networking site in ***python/django.***I have decided to use following technologies to implement this.I have some doubt regarding these technologies which i had planned to use. If anyone can help me regarding this it will be helpful.I want to avoid the  bottle necks when it is scale into the thousands of connections .

- Apache  as web-server
- Mailgun cloud-based email service (Heroku addon)
- RabbitMQ as a message queue(Heroku addon)if required
- MySQL  5.1 as database system.(Xeround addon)
- Git as file content management
- Memcache to reduce database load (optional)
- Heroku as a cloud based plattform(staging and live)

Which storage i have to use for static files delivery or any heroku addon is there for static or content delivery?

Please advice.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: "Git as file content management" - do you mean version control?

Comment: yes git used for version control

Comment: You can use S3 for storage for your static content - see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Comment: can anyone help me in choosing the webserver? apache or tornado? which is more better for a social networking site?

Comment: If you're using Heroku, you don't need to worry about the webserver. Personally if I was hosting the webserver myself nginx+uWSGI. As Jon mentions, use S3 for static content. I'd use Postgresql over MySQL (Not least because Heroku's DB options run on Postgres!)

Answer (score 1):

apache Solr for fast indexing,
virtual-env ,
a library that provides connection pooling (SQLAlchemy),
django-evolution or south for migration.

Comment: SQLAlchemy and the django ORM can't be used together.